# C# Windows Service Starting and stopping

Tags: c#, windows-services

Just trying to save some clicking and typing while I create a service.  Right now the steps are:

1. cmd prompt  net stop service name
2. compile service
3. cmd prompt  net start service name

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, anybody here know of one?

Thank you.

Comment: You could put it in a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure steps 1 & 3 as [pre and post build events for the project](http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/). Step 1 will be executed before compiling, and step 3 will execute after a successful build. This should automate things nicely.

Answer (score 1):

When creating services, I embed the service class in a console app and add some interactive code to run the service's .run method and stop/start, etc. This makes it MUCH easier to test and debug.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached is rather nice as well... All of my services behave like a normal program when run under a debugger.

Comment: Environment.UserInteractive does the job nicely as well. If UserInteractive, show the UI, even if there's not a debugger attached. If not UserInteractive, do the usual service startup.

Comment: Both nice tips! I'll investigate those as alternatives next time around.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project > properties > build events tab

You can use the pre-build and post build events to do steps 1 and 3 respectively.